# Core Animation... cyclic animations?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, core-animation

To phrase my question as simply as possible, is there a way to create a core animation sequence to repeat over and over until a stop?

Specifically, I'm making a custom class that I want to have a -start and -stop method that will cause it to pulsate. Writing the animation code for the pulse is not the problem, rather, how to make it repetitive?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW8), you do it by creating an animation with an extremely large `repeatCount` (code excerpted from the documentation I linked to):

```
// create the animation that will handle the pulsing.
CABasicAnimation* pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animation];

// over a one second duration, and run an infinite
// number of times
pulseAnimation.duration = 1.0;
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

// we want it to fade on, and fade off, so it needs to
// automatically autoreverse.. this causes the intensity
// input to go from 0 to 1 to 0
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
```

**edit**: The OP asked how to stop the animation. From the [next paragraph](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation%5Fguide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW9) in the documentation:

> You start an explicit animation by
>   sending a `addAnimation:forKey:` message
>   to the target layer, passing the
>   animation and an identifier as
>   parameters. Once added to the target
>   layer the explicit animation will run
>   until the animation completes, or it
>   is removed from the layer. The
>   identifier used to add an animation to
>   a layer is also used to stop it by
>   invoking `removeAnimationForKey:`. You
>   can stop all animations for a layer by
>   sending the layer a
>   `removeAllAnimations` message.

Comment: Contrary to the comment in the code sample you pasted, 1e100 is not infinite—it's just 10**100. The INFINITY constant, defined in math.h, would be better.

Comment: Responded in the answer since there isn't enough room in the comments.

Comment: @PeterHosey conceptually it's the same. INFINITY is defined as HUGE_VALF. However, 1e100 is greater than the maximum value admissible for a float. I prefer to use MAXFLOAT.

Comment: These animations go black when backgrounding and then coming back in from background. How does one fix that?

Comment: @PsychoDad I would recommend you ask a new question with more detail. Just asking in a comment means that I'm the only one likely to see it, you can't fit much detail on your question, and there's not much room to answer you in a comment.

Comment: Strictly saying, you should use indirect symbolic constant `HUGE_VALF` instead of bare value or other symbols. You can't say they are same. Only their result on specific implementation is same. In strict manner, `INFINITY` or `1e100f` are all wrong.