# iOS Animation 2D game

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, scroll

I'm making an application, for the iPhone, which is a 2D game.
I have done all the spritesheets, but now i need to animate some of them particulary :
My game is a game where your hero should avoid some obstacles. The borders should move to give the impression that the game is more difficult by increasing the speed (so the hero looks like going faster and faster). I have my image of the border, but really don't know how to animate it dynamically, and when the end of the image is coming, put the top of the image to come after it.

Note : I know how to make a translation, to animate an image but here i need to animate it faster and faster, so to change dynamically the speed of the animation.

Thanks for your help !

Code or a UIImageView :

```
nuages_bas2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-100, 0, 160, 1000)];
UIImage * ImageNuages = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_nuage.png"];
nuages_bas2.image = ImageNuages;
nuages_bas2.alpha = 0.0f;
[menu_principale addSubview:nuages_bas2];
[nuages_bas2 release];
```

Code for one of the animations :

```
- (void)AnimationNuagesBas2
{
nuages_bas2.alpha = 1.0f;
CABasicAnimation * nuagesbas2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
nuagesbas2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:480.0f];
nuagesbas2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-960.0f];
nuagesbas2.duration = 35.0f;
nuagesbas2.repeatCount = 10;
[nuages_bas2.layer addAnimation:nuagesbas2 forKey:@"nuagesbas2"];
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're using? So we know what classes you're using to do the animations etc...

Comment: Done. My UIImageView must be repeat when comes to the end of translation, and animation of translation must have a dynamic duration.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want it to get faster after each repeat(so it gets faster and faster 10 times with your current code). Or do you want it to progressively speed up during each repeat?

Comment: I just want to speed up progressively after each repeat.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, if you're making a game, you probably should not be using UIKit unless it's something very simple. You should have a look at libraries like [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)

As for this question, you may want to look at [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). I'll attempt to sketch out some code that will do something like this, but you'll probably want to modify it(Also, I don't have the means to test it).

Note, what follows below is a hack that consists of creating a keyframe animation where the object goes back and forth each time with a smaller duration.

```
- (void)AnimationNuagesBas2
{
    nuages_bas2.alpha = 1.0f;
    CAKeyframeAnimation * nuagesbas2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    float from = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:480];
    float to = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-960];
    int repeatCount = 10;
    float duration = 6;
    float durationDecrease = 0.5;
    float t = 0;
    NSMutableArray * values = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray * times = [NSMutableArray array];
    [values addObject:from];
    [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++){
        t += duration/2;
    [values addObject:to];
    [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:t]];
        t += duration/2;
    [values addObject:from];
    [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:t]];
    duration -= durationDecrease;
    }

    [nuages_bas2.layer addAnimation:nuagesbas2 forKey:@"nuagesbas2"];
}
```

Another approach would be to set yourself as the delegate to the `CABasicAnimation` and set it with a repeatCount of 0. Then, every time it's done, you re-initiate it with a smaller duration.

Comment: I'll try your solution on this afternoon. Do you have any idea for how making a background moving with a UIImageView ? And that the image restart after the end of the fisrt image comes ? So i could make an infinity background with one picture

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about having a background move(isn't it as simple as having a UIImageView behind everything else that moves?). As for repeating infinitely, the best way seems to have a very large repeatCount

Comment: Yes it's only this, i want to have a UIImageView making a background that moves ! But I don't know how to make this just with one image ?

Comment: Have an image that's wider than the screen and move it maybe? It's hard to say without a more detailed explanation of what you mean. Check this answer for an example of how to do an infinite repeat with something going back and forth between fromValue and toValue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784365/core-animation-cyclic-animations (use animation.autoreverses)

Comment: I know it's hard and furthermore i can't post some pictures to explain you because of no reputation points :/ I'll try to see with all your help, thanks a lot